# Need to run 3 queries that use the result of the previous query.. on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a website that will show specific records to some folks in the company here. I am using PHP, HTML and MYSLQ to create it.

This is the basic layout I am trying to present:

It is an html website, and each row has collapsible rows on 2 levels:

Reference Number > Entries > Invoices

So in this logic, a **Reference Number** can have one or multiple **Entries** and an **Entry** can have one or multiple **Invoices**.

The html table is a no brainer, the problem is to feed the data into the website.

### How I made it work...

Using PHP I created a procedure that first queries the database for the **References**, then I do a `while` loop to go through the **References** and then using the reference number I query the **Entries** and do a `while` loop to go through them and use the **Entry Number** to query for the **Invoices**.

Now, I am an amateur coder, but I do know that putting the query inside a while loop is extremely bad practice. So I am struggling to making this work properly.

Furthermore, I want this to work by using stored procedures so that all the querying happens on mysql server, rather than on the client side.

Here are the queries:

Query 1 (Main level):

```
SELECT  
oc.sNumCajaTrailer AS Caja,  
oc.dFechaCruce AS FechaSalida,  
t.sNombre AS Transportista, 
tfc.sCveTrafico AS Reference <--- This is the key for the next query

FROM cb_detalle_orden_carga doc

JOIN cb_orden_carga oc ON doc.iConsecutivoOrdenCarga = oc.iConsecutivo 
JOIN cu_transfer t ON oc.sCveTransfer = t.sCveTransfer 
JOIN cb_trafico tfc ON doc.sCveTrafico = tfc.sCveTrafico 
JOIN cu_cliente cte ON tfc.sCveCliente = cte.sCveCliente

WHERE  
(oc.dFechaCruce IS NULL OR oc.dFechaCruce IN (fechaSalida)) 
AND tfc.sCveCliente = 'CLT_6840' AND (doc.sCveTrafico LIKE '%N16%' OR doc.sCveTrafico LIKE '%N17%')

GROUP BY doc.sCveTrafico
```

Query 2 (FirstSubLevel)

```
SELECT  b.sCveEntradaBodega AS Entry, <----- This is the key for next query 
        cp.sNombreProveedor AS NombreProveedor, 
        b.dFechaIngreso AS FechaIngreso,
        b.iCantidadBultos AS Bultos,
        cb.sDescripcion AS TipoBultos

FROM cb_bulto b

JOIN cb_entrada_bodega eb ON b.sCveEntradaBodega = eb.sCveEntradaBodega
JOIN cu_cliente_proveedor cp ON eb.sCveProveedor = cp.sCveProveedor
    AND cp.sCveCliente = eb.sCveCliente
JOIN cb_detalle_orden_carga doc ON b.iConsecutivo = doc.iConsecutivoBulto
JOIN cb_orden_carga oc ON doc.iConsecutivoOrdenCarga = oc.iConsecutivo
JOIN ct_bulto cb ON b.sCveBulto = cb.sCveBulto

WHERE b.sCveTrafico = Reference
```

Query 3 (Second and last sublevel)

```
SELECT  
f.sNumero AS numFactura,
eb.sNumTalon AS numGuia,
pf.sCveClienteProveedorProducto AS numParte,
pf.iCantidadProducto AS cantidadProducto,
f.sNumeroPedido AS numOrden,
b.iCantidadBultos AS cantidadBultos,
tb.sDescripcion AS tipoBultos

FROM

cb_bulto b

JOIN cb_relacion_remesa_banco_facturas rbf ON b.iConsecutivo = rbf.iConsecutivoBulto
JOIN cb_factura f ON rbf.iFolio = f.iFolio
JOIN cb_entrada_bodega eb ON b.sCveEntradaBodega = eb.sCveEntradaBodega
JOIN cb_producto_factura pf ON f.iFolio = pf.iFolio
JOIN ct_bulto tb ON b.sCveBulto = tb.sCveBulto

WHERE

b.sCveEntradaBodega = Entry
```

Any ideas????!!!!

Comment: What do you mean with `this is extremely illegal`? And maybe google: `nested stored procedures`

Comment: I'll edit it, I mean it's a really bad practice in mysql to make a loop that contains a query (the query is repeated on each iteration, at least 30 times).

Comment: Also read:  http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2005/10/nesting-mysql-cursor-loops.html    and `30 times` in nothing, but you can make it better/faster with `prepared statement`.  http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The first while iterates 30 times, second one iterates about 10 times on each iteration, and the last while iterates 15 - 20 times over the first and second. That makes it around 6000 queries or so. It takes the webpage about 10 minutes to popualte completely. I tried the prepared statements, but I can't seem to find how to send a parameter for the IN clause.

Comment: If the data is not update in short time, then do this here in a cronjob and create an faster table from the results. If that wont work, may thing about your implemntation again: can this done in another way? By the way: You never before talked about `the IN clause`. Kinda hard to help. But i have given some tips: `nested stored procedures` or `nesting-mysql-cursor-loops` or `use prepared statments`. If nothing works, rething your application.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll check those ideas and try to make it work.